# TypeError: record is undefined

Tags: javascript, cookies, typeerror

I am making a JS game, and i have to update the highscores and display them using cookies. The functions below are in a file highscore.js

```
function getHighScoreTable() {
    var table = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Contruct the cookie name
        var cookie_name = "player" + i;
        // Get the cookie value using the cookie name
        var cookie_value = getCookie(cookie_name);
        // If the cookie does not exist exit from the for loop
        if (!cookie_value) {
            break;
        }
        // Extract the name and score of the player from the cookie value
        var value_array = cookie_value.split("~");
        var pname = value_array[0];
        var pscore = value_array[1];
        // Add a new score record at the end of the array
        table.push(new ScoreRecord(pname, pscore));
    }
    return table;
}
//
// This function stores the high score table to the cookies
//
function setHighScoreTable(table) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // If i is more than the length of the high score table exit
        // from the for loop
        if (i >= table.length) break;
        // Contruct the cookie name
        var cookie_name = "player" + i;
        var record = table[i];
        var cookie_value = record.name + "~" + record.score; // **error here = TypeError: record is undefined**
        // Store the ith record as a cookie using the cookie name
        setCookie(cookie_name, cookie_value);
    }
}
```

in my game.js, i have a function gameOver() which handles the highscore etc and clearing the gametimers.

```
function gameOver() {
    clearInterval(gameInterval);
    clearInterval(timeInterval);
    alert("game over!");
    var scoreTable = getHighScoreTable();
    var record = ScoreRecord(playerName, score);
    var insertIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < scoreTable.length; i++) {
        if (score >= scoreTable[i].score) {
            insertIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (scoreTable.length == 0) {
        scoreTable.push(record);
    } else {
        scoreTable.splice(insertIndex, 0, record);
    }
    setHighScoreTable(scoreTable);
    showHighScoreTable(scoreTable);
}
```

When the gameover is called in game, error occurs in **setHighScoreTable**(table) and the error is that record (i.e. table[i]) is undefined. Need help in this bug.

Comment: Shouldn't you write `getCookie(cookie_name);` instead of `getCookie("cookie_name");`?

Comment: You could just do `scoreTable.push(record); scoreTable.sort( (a,b) => a.score - b.score );`

Comment: Beside that `getCookie(cookie_name)` thing I don't see any issue in your code. Can you provide the exact error message and the line where the error appears?

Comment: I agree w/ gus.  The cookie_name thing will prevent you adding any records from cookies, but it won't affect `setHighScoreTable`

Comment: @gus27, yes my mistake, thanks, but it still does not fix the error

Comment: Just found another problem: Where is the `score` variable defined you used in the `for` loop in `gameOver`?

Comment: Ok, so ... this is happening because `playerName` is undefined when you create the new `ScoreRecord` or the `ScoreRecord` constructor has an issue

Comment: @gus27, 'playerName' and 'score' are global variables in my game.js.

Comment: I think I have the solution, check my answer

Comment: @SuhaibAhmad Try that sort in my comment earlier.  Can cut out a few lines of code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ScoreRecord is defined something like this:

```
function ScoreRecord(name, score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}
```

The problem is you are doing:

```
record = ScoreRecord(playerName, score);
```

This will just call the constructor as if it were a function - but it returns nothing.  Just add the `new` keyword to create a new object instead

```
record = new ScoreRecord(playerName, score);
```

You could also do something like this to prevent the constructor being called as a normal function:

```
function ScoreRecord(name, score) {
    "use strict"

    if (!(this instanceof ScoreRecord)) {
        throw new Error("ScoreRecord must be called with the new keyword");
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}
```

Comment: yes i have the break code if it exceeds the table.length